# Sizing widget equally (xml approach only)

Tags: android, dpi

I have one problem with UI widget sizing, see 2 devices below as an example,

```
1.) Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7"
- Pixels : 1024x600 (mdpi)
- DPI : 160
- Density : 1.0
2.) Samsung Nexus 10 2013
- Pixels : 2560x1600 (xhdpi)
- DPI : 320
- Density : 2.0
```

If I place a widget with 50dp, by using px = dp (DPI / 160), it would be **50px for Tab 7"** and **100px for Nexus 10**. But in term of percentage, 50px is equal to **4.88% of screen width on Tab 7"** while 100px is **3.9% of screen width on Nexus 10**.

But, I need this widget to appear with same width percentage. So, I came up with 2 options.

A. Calculate at run time by getting the physical pixels and apply percentage, then resize the widget.

B. Calculate size and place in < dimen > in different xml file (sw600dp and sw700dp for my case).

As of now, I'm using option A to calculate size and set at runtime. It works well but I'm afraid that the calculation could affect the performance. If I choose option B, I will need to calculate size for every widget in every screen (**50dp for Tab 7" and 62.5dp for Nexus 10 will result as 4.8% on both**). But, if I want to change this value later or some manufacturer introduce new device with difference DPI or pixels (imagine, 7" tablet with hdpi resolution, 1.5 density, 240 DPI), I will have to redo all the calculation and update or provide new xml again.

So, my question is, is there an option C which will not slow down the performance and not taking a lot of manual calculation into account in future?

P.S. Sorry, I forgot to mentioned that I also using weight approach with my static widgets already, but my question is about dynamic-generate widget. For example,

- a gridlayout that showing 5 columns on Landscape Tablet
- a scrollview to show 4 rows per page on Phone
- an ImageView with 5% padding
- an ImageView with an aspect ratio on every device.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask for a little more detail about why you need it to be the same width percentage on all devices? Are you trying to match the width of some other bit of UI? It may be that there's a different way of laying things out that might eliminate the width restriction that you're having to impose.

Comment: For example, a gridlayout that showing 5 columns on Landscape Tablet, having a scrollview to show 4 rows per page on Phone or an ImageView to has exact same padding percentage on every device.

Answer (score 1):

dp are almost equal on all devices in size, not in screen %

If you need same screen % then just get display size & calculate desired % of it. Then dynamically apply to your widget

Comment: Thank you, but that is already my option A (which is my current solution).